# Cloudfront, No subdomain, and tainted canvas

Tags: html, canvas, amazon-s3, html5-canvas, amazon-cloudfront

For two weeks we have been attempting to draw to canvas to capture a HTML 5 video as a still frame.
The problem is the files are being served on a subdomain, and we receive variations of unable to draw to tainted canvas in all major browsers.

The website, let's say mysite.com, reads media files, stored in an s3 bucket, with public access, cross origin headers, to a cloudfront distribution, with a cname, media.mysite.com, setup in Route53, as an A record with alias for media.mysite.com pointing to the cloudfront distribution.

Cloudfront is configured to pass along the origin headers.

Here's a bit of our code:

```
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var videoElement = player.el().querySelector('video');
    videoElement.crossorigin = "anonymous";

    player.controlBar.takeSnapshot = player.controlBar.addChild( takeSnapshot );
    player.controlBar.takeSnapshot.on('click', function(){
        canvas.width = videoElement.videoWidth;
        canvas.height = videoElement.videoHeight;
        ctx.drawImage(videoElement, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        console.log(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
    });
```

After all the configuring with various AWS services, we were able to get this to work only in chrome, while still failing in Safari.

Sooo...how does one use their own assets on their own sites without tainting their own canvases with as much cross-browser compatibility as possible?

Comment: Check out this resource on how to configure the server and client to satisfy cross-origin security requirements: http://enable-cors.org/

Comment: Thanks, I've read this resource before from cover to cover. It works for images, but HTML5 video to canvas does not work in Safari with CORS.